# Open Outlook from Access to scan Inbox

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook, vba

I look for an email in Outlook using VBA in Access. It doesn't work all the time.

I wonder if I do not declare my variables officially, or do not open Outlook properly.

Also, is there a way to open Outlook, refresh the inbox folder, and then begin scanning?

The error is either one of two things, the remote server you are trying to connect to is not available", or "object not declared" as if the Outlook application was never opened.

```
Dim ns                  As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objOL               As Outlook.Application
Dim folder              As MAPIFolder
Dim item                As Object
Dim msg                 As MailItem
Dim objAttachments      As Outlook.Attachments

Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'The line below will error out occasionally
'  with a remote serve not available...
Set ns = Session.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

Set folder = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

For Each item In folder.Items
    DoEvents
    If (item.Class = olMail) And (item.UnRead) Then
        ' This message has not been read.  Display it modally
        Set msg = item
        'Debug.Print (msg.Subject)
        'Debug.Print (msg.SenderEmailAddress)
        tempString = CStr(msg.Subject)
        If Mid(tempString, 1, 4) = "qqqq" Then
            'Debug.Print (tempString)
            'create new directory
            If updateFlag = 0 Then
                'this checks if the directory already exists,
                ' if it does just skip creating the directory since we do not
                ' want to override previous saved attached inventory files.
                If Dir(strFolderpath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
                    Createdir True, strFolderpath
                End If
            End If
            updateFlag = 1

            'Debug.Print msg.Subject
            'instantiate attachments object for each openned email
            Set objAttachments = msg.Attachments
            lngCount = objAttachments.Count
            'if you want to open all the emails uncomment next line
            'msg.Display True
            For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
                ' Save attachment before deleting from item.
                ' Get the file name.
                strFile = objAttachments.item(i).FileName
                ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
                strFile = strFolderpath & "\" & strFile
                WriteLogFile "File saved from blabla@blbl inbox, file path: " & strFile
                ' Save the attachment as a file.
                objAttachments.item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
            Next i

            msg.UnRead = False
        End If
    End If
Next
'close the outlook application.
'objOL.Quit
```

I tried opening Outlook, then closing it and reopening it, but that doesn't work as well. Is there a more proper way to open Outlook? And how to refresh the inbox once open, wait for refresh to complete, and then scan inbox?

Comment: Can you show the rest of the code?

Comment: Ok, i added it, the tabbing got a little funky. Also ignore the file paths, they are variables passed from another function. those are all correct though.

Comment: What exactly does *"it doesn't work"* mean?

Comment: Sorry, it appears Om3r edited the error message that it was displaying. It would error on the commented line saying either one of two things, "the remote server you are trying to connect to is not available", or "object not declared" as if outlook aplication was never opened. Hence why i wonder if i do not open outlook a proper way.

Comment: I am aware that like half of the VBA libraries do not work, is it simply a result of bad libraries? Because all my googling has pointed me to the above code.

Comment: `Set objAttachments = msg.Attachments
 lngCount = objAttachments.Count
 For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1`  could probably be simplified with `for each i in msg.attachments`  then you could just `i.saveasfile strfile`  ???